# changing fill colors when combo box is disabled

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days. The solution seems simple, but I haven't found one yet.

I'm working with Flex 3, and I'm trying to change the color of a ComboBox when it is disabled into something lighter. The current CSS is this:

```
ComboBox {
color:#000000;
fillAphas: 1, .5, .55, .35;
fillColors: #ffffff, #cccccc, #999999, #666666;
fontWeight: normal;
backgroundAlpha: 1;
fontSize:11;
}
```

The problem is that when i use the backgroundDisabledColor property, the enabled as well as the disabled combo boxes are all altered with the new color. Is there a way to set a disabled fill color property, or somehow turn off the fill colors when the combo box is disabled? Thanks.

**
Seeing as I could not change the fill Colors for a disabled combobox directly with a css property, and flex 3 does not like css attribute selectors, I added a property to link to a skin when disabled and simply made a ComboBox skin with lighter colors. This seemed to be the best option. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try setting the disabledColor [style](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html#styleSummary)?

I was pretty sure a component is disabled, visually, by drawing a semi transparent graphic on top of it.  I'm not sure I'd recommend trying to change the background color in order to visually communicate "Disabled".

Changing the universal "ComboBox" style will change all ComboBoxes.  But, you could create a named style:

```
.disabledComboStyle {
color:#000000;
fillAphas: 1, .5, .55, .35;
fillColors: #ffffff, #cccccc, #999999, #666666;
fontWeight: normal;
backgroundAlpha: 1;
fontSize:11;
}
```

And specify it on your disabled component using the styleName style:

```
<mx:ComboBox styleName = "disabledComboStyle" />
```

However, style computations are known to be a performance heavy operation, so I'm not sure I'd recommend switching styles like this a lot.

Comment: The xml that calls the combo box is as follows:

    <mx:ComboBox id="dosageUnitCombo" itemRenderer="mx.controls.Label" dataProvider="{dosageUnitCollection}" change="changeDosage()" toolTip="{dosageUnitCombo.selectedItem.elementDisplay}" focusThickness="4" labelField="elementDisplay" width="{otherDosageSelected?60:121}" enabled="{addPriv &amp;&amp; dosageInput.text.length>0}"/>

So, basically there is a function that enables the combo box based on whether there is something inputted into another input field.

There is also no default text within the combo box.

Comment: @RyanSchulze Did you intend to ask a follow up question?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fairly new at this website. disabledColor only changes the color of the text within the combobox, but there is no default text. Therefore, I still want to change the color of the comboBox to display that it is not yet enabled. Assigning the combo box to a 'disabledComboStyle' class would make it look disabled always. I want the style of the ComboBox to switch dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how flex's attributes work but a general rule to select elements with CSS like in your situation is the following:

```
ComboBox[attribute='value'] {
  //the changed properties
}
```